# I'm using C++ for some basic graphics. I want to know that how to read vertices, indexes and faces and how to use faces in array list?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
    stringstream ss(buff);
    string s;

    ss >> s;

    if (s == "v")
    {
        vec3 v;
        ss >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
        vertexPositionSet.push_back(v);
    }
    if (s == "vn")
    {
        vec3 v;
        ss >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
        vertexNormalSet.push_back(v);
    }
    if (s == "f")
    {
        // I'm unable to go better beyond this..?I'm attaching some face vertices for more explaination.
```

f 32//1 2//1 33//1
f 1//2 2//2 3//2
f 31//3 2//3 32//3
f 30//4 2//4 31//4   // how to read these?
        }

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, 
It will helps you

```
vec3 v,v1;

ss >> v.x >> ch1 >> ch2 >> v1.x;
   ss >> v.y >> ch1 >> ch2 >> v1.y;
   ss >> v.z >> ch1 >> ch2 >> v1.z;
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Hey Kashif!! I tried this solution and it worked. bundle of thanks. So nice of you !!!:-)